# Role or Groups? DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I'm developing an application, and I'm not sure about permissions. I have two types of user, client and supermarket. The only thing i want is to limit the views (What one can see and the other can't). Is the best approach role or groups ? Or both together. I get the expected behavior with one or the other, but I don't know which is correct

Comment: For example, you can add groups and set appropriate permissions for them. Then assign users to the appropriate group.

Comment: Roles and Groups are synonymous (the same) in your context unless your setup is larger than explained. Permissions should be assigned to either a role or a group, when a user is assigned to the group (or possesses the role), they have granted permission. I would opt for "role" in your case since it reads better, as "groups" can be interpreted as something else such as group: "floor staff", where some may possess the role "manager" with elevated permissions, but they share a group.

Comment: THK, @KeaganFouche solved my doubt